# webapp2 post operation not updating datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, post, webapp2

I am developing a web application using google appengine.

I am trying to update an existing entry in the table but my post operation does not seem to be working.

post script:

```
r = requests.post("http://localhost:8080", data={'type': 'user', 'id':
'11111', 'name': 'test'})
```

When running the script there are no errors in the console and when prining r.text I can see the updated name but the page on localhost does not show the updated name and the datastore user still has its previous name.

My model for the main page is:

```
class Page(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        ...
    def post(self):
        user = User().get_user(self.request.get('id'))  // query user from data store
        user.name = self.request.get('name')
        user.put()
        // update jinja template
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.request.get('id')` is a `string`.  You want to use an `integer` for the id, or build a key (I am assuming you are using `ndb`):

```
user = ndb.Key('User', int(self.request.get('id'))).get()
```

Comment: This still is not updating my datastore. Again, the content from the post is updated but the actual static page and datastore is not.

Comment: Printing the current user after updating the name field does not show the updated name in the User Object.... weird

Comment: is `Page()` connected to your root url `http://localhost:8080`?  May be an issue of datastore consistency.  Wait 10 seconds and check again for the change.

Comment: Also, log `self.request` to see what is being posted.